# Adding Handler using 'AddressOf'

Tags: vb.net, button, dynamic, handler, addressof

When  trying to add an event handler to a dynamically created button I get an an error:

```
Dim Itm As New Button
Itm.Name = "Itm" & i
Itm.Height = 62
Itm.Width = 159
Itm.Text = Temp(i, 0).ToUpper
Itm.Left = (F * 165)
Itm.Visible = True
Itm.BackColor = Colour
Itm.ForeColor = Color.Black
AddHandler Itm.Click, AddressOf Me.Itm_Click
Me.pnlItemButton1.Controls.Add(Itm)
i = i + 1
If i > Temp.Length - 1 Then
    GoTo Exit1
End If
```

I get an error on the AddressOf line:

> "Item_Click is not a member of windowsapplication1.main"

I feel this is because I have set the name to be `"Itm" & i` but using `AddressOf Me.Itm(i)_Click` also presents an error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Where is the event handler `Itm_Click` declared? Show more context.

Comment: Sorry- im new to coding! I dont think i have declared it? How should i declare it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the [event handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z7x8ys3(v=vs.90).aspx) `Itm_Click` and it must be accessible.

For example (presuming that your array `Temp` exists somewhere):

```
Public Class Demo
    Protected Sub Itm_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 

    End Sub

    Public Sub DemoMethod()
        For i As Int32 = 1 To Temp.Length - 1
            Dim Itm As New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
            Itm.Name = "Itm" & i
            Itm.Height = 62
            Itm.Width = 159
            Itm.Text = Temp(i, 0).ToUpper
            Itm.Left = (F * 165)
            Itm.Visible = True
            Itm.BackColor = Colour.White
            Itm.ForeColor = Color.Black
            AddHandler Itm.Click, AddressOf Me.Itm_Click
            Me.pnlItemButton1.Controls.Add(Itm)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

You can use this event handler for all dynamically created buttons. You get the button that was clicked from the `sender` argument:

```
Protected Sub Itm_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    Dim actualButton = Ctype(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Button)
    Dim name = actualButton.Name
End Sub
```